# How to run a sub on Excel Ribbon action?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ribbon

I've recently installed a free Excel Add-in called Essential Regression. I want to make a ribbon button to call a specific macro from the VBA project associated with that excel add-in er22.xlam file.

So, basically i want to run the macro multistart that is located in the module ModMultiRegStart in the VBA project mult24.xls (er22.xlam)

After some googling i found this:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
  <tab id="CustomTab"
       label="Eregression">
    <group id="SimpleControls"
           label="Essential Regression">
      <button id="Button1"
              size="large"
              label="Start Eregression"
              onAction="mult24.xls!multistart"/>
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

It generates the button but it doesn't work when I press it. I'm guessing mult24.xls!multistart is not the correct way to refer to that particular sub but I have no clue on how i should refer to it.

I can still go to the developper tab and select the VBA project and press F5, then select the macro multistart but it would be much easier if I didn't have to do that every time.

Any help?

Comment: What is "mult24.xls"?  By the "xls" file extension, it looks like it's as an old format that pre-dates ribbons, so you're not going to get that to work.  The workbook would have an ".xlsm" file extension if it was an Office 2007 or 2010 format and supported running macro code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your onAction button is trying to call a macro in multi25.xls, but you say the macro is in er22.xlam.  In general, the syntax for calling a Sub / Function is as follows:

myWorkbook.xlsm!MyModule.MySub

You CAN ignore the module if the sub is uniquely named, but it is best to include for clarity.